# strange looking allocation and some description for String concatenation optimization code

Tags: java, c++, optimization, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I was reviewing OpenJDK JVM's [String concatentation optimization code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp) when I encountered the following:

```
    cnode = recv->isa_CallStaticJava();
    if (cnode == NULL) {
      alloc = recv->isa_Allocate();
      if (alloc == NULL) {
        break;
      }
      // Find the constructor call
      Node* result = alloc->result_cast();
      if (result == NULL || !result->is_CheckCastPP() || alloc->in(TypeFunc::Memory)->is_top()) {
        // strange looking allocation
#ifndef PRODUCT
        if (PrintOptimizeStringConcat) {
          tty->print("giving up because allocation looks strange ");
          alloc->jvms()->dump_spec(tty); tty->cr();
        }
#endif
        break;
      }
```

First, I'm not sure what is `cnode`. I'm thinking `cnode` is some type of object representation for a call to the plus sign "+" (for String concatenation). Now, `result` is a call to the plus sign's corresponding `StringBuilder`'s constructor. Ok, not sure again but I think that if there is no node created or the node is not a CheckCastPP or the object representation of the created allocation is on top of the stack, the optimization will not continue.

What is a CheckCastPP and could my interpretation be right?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, address the  HotSpot dev mailing list.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, sure? I thought only discussion of bugs and issues are allowed there.

Comment: Maybe I have spoken too loosely, the list does not necessarily have "dev" in its name, but perhaps one with "interest" in the name.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/ mentions about dev mailing lists only :(

Comment: I would still try at hotspot-compiler-dev, they are usually friendly about questions such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking at - `PhaseStringOpts::build_candidate(CallStaticJavaNode* call)`  - starts from `StringBuilder.toString()` call node and tries to unroll the use chain looking for the typical concatenation pattern:

```
StringBuilder AllocateNode -> append() CallStaticJavaNode -> ... -> toString()
```

The fragment you've shown checks the type of the current node in the chain. If it is `CallStaticJavaNode`, then it should be a call to `StringBuilder.append()`, otherwise it should be `AllocateNode`.

On the JVM level a creation of a new object is

1. memory allocation, followed by
2. implicit cast to the target object type, followed by
3. invocation of `<init>` method (the constructor)

For the correctly generated bytecode

```
    new java/lang/StringBuilder
    dup
    invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder.<init>()V
```

there will be exactly one use of `AllocNode` that casts the result to `StringBuilder`.
That's what `result->is_CheckCastPP()` asserts.